# require an array from a file javacsript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

In a javacscript file I have something that looks like this,

```
module.exports = {
   ROUTES: [
    {"route1" : "route-1"},
    {"route2" : "route-2"},
    {"route3" : "route-3"}
  ]
}
```

I am doing the following to use these values in another file,

`const routes = require("/routes");`

meaning to access the values I have to do the following,

`routes.ROUTES.route1`

Is it possible to import the ROUTES array directly from the file so I can do,

`ROUTES.route1`

Comment: Export only `[...]`? `require(...).ROUTES`?

Comment: Destructure the property on require? `const { ROUTES } = ...`

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using common JS modules, you can use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring):

```
const { ROUTES } = require('./routes');
```

You could also export the routes array directly if you don't have anything else in the file:

```
module.exports = [
  {"route1" : "route-1"},
  {"route2" : "route-2"},
  {"route3" : "route-3"}
]
```

That way you could keep your import:

```
const routes = require("/routes");
```

Comment: Or directly export the array. That way they can keep their import.